# How we use useState when we want to delete an object in a array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJQEt.png)

**When user click on this the specific  object is get deleted using splice method but cannot change its state What's the  issue in that ??  **

Comment: could you write this code inside your question instead of a sceenshot?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

`Change(Name)` ,instead of `Change(arr)` in your `DeleteOne` method

see  [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)